# Ruby: How to demonize MailMan (incoming mail processing microframework)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mailman, whenever

I'm using [mailman gem](http://github.com/titanous/mailman) for fetching email from pop3 server and send it to Rails application. What should I do to make mailman be as daemon? Please, tell me easiest way to do it.

May be [whenever gem](http://github.com/javan/whenever) can help? Something like:

```
  every :reboot do

    command "cd /home/rails/root && ruby bin/mailman_fetcher.rb"

  end
```

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at Daemons, http://daemons.rubyforge.org/

Comment: Don't forget to set 'Mailman.config.ignore_stdin = true' to avoid some issues when running as a daemon.

Comment: +1 for Jonathan, took me an hour to get it to work with daemons.

Comment: Jonathan, thank you!! just spent 4 hours trying to figure out why Mailman as a daemon was just exiting.